# missing out on some basic ruby concepts

Tags: ruby, module

I have a ruby project with the following structure

```
(root)
-bin/
-lib/
-specs/
  - base.rb
  - cli.rb
  - settings.rb
```

The code in cli.rb has the following,

**This file contains a bunch of require stmts which are used in the file**

```
module X
  class cli
    #some-code
  end
end
```

The code in base.rb has this one line that i fail to understand,

```
module X
  class Base
    def setup
     @cli = Cli.new.global --> I don't understand this line as there is no require statement above that.
     # more code
    end
  end
end
```

I'm probably missing some basic concepts here as i'm pretty new to ruby.

Thanks

Adding the line in the code which makes me wonder about this issue,

https://github.com/agent462/sensu-cli/blob/master/lib/sensu-cli/base.rb#L4

Comment: Im really not sure what your question is

Comment: @ptiern I wanted to know how can you specify the line i mentioned above without specifying any require/include statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my original assumption on what was causing the confusion, so I've changed the entire answer.

Because the supposedly undefined identifier (`Cli`) is inside a method definition (`X::base#setup`), it isn't resolved when the code is loaded. It is only resolved when the method is called. This allows a file to include `base.rb` without having defined `Cli`. The only time a real problem will arise is if `setup` is called AND `Cli` is not defined.

Comment: @itdoesnotwork well, that does not answer my question. In main.rb there is no require "other.rb"..will that still work. May be you can look at this line which will give you a better picture of my problem. https://github.com/agent462/sensu-cli/blob/master/lib/sensu-cli/base.rb#L4

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue now. I'll edit the answer. Tell me if it's any closer.

Comment: If it resolves when the method is called, i just checked-again to see if it's calling the method anywhere in the code but couldn't find anything of that sort. maybe i'm missing out on the flow somewhere. If it is what you mention, then it should result in an error

Comment: [this](https://github.com/agent462/sensu-cli/blob/17775061ee71a5af85a8f31f72ddbbda0c0177ac/bin/sensu) file calls setup after including "sensu-cli" which includes pretty much everything, so it should actually work.